Fetch request error in react native, getting a 'Network Request Failed' every time doing an image request for a blob in typescript
I am using expo router for this project, and I am creating a system to show cards from a book api i am receiving. I'd like to show the cover of the book that the user will be searching, to do so I'd need to get one of the many ISBN codes provided when using the book api. Some of these codes don't work so I'll need to create some logic to test each code until an image is returned. I have implemented this code using blob. I've added a miniature error handling process and every time I try to do a search (I have a console.log placed to show the error message), I recieve 'Network Request Failed'. I will be showing the two files which are causing this error.
BookCard.tsx
import { Spinner, View, Text } from 'tamagui'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { Doc } from '@/interfaces/bookApiResults'
import { Image } from 'react-native'
import checkAndFetchCover from '@/utils/checkAndFetchCover'

type BookCardProps = {
  book: Doc
}

interface ImageSource {
  uri?: string;
}

// Error may occur due to props!
export default function BookCard({ book } : BookCardProps ) {
  //Set Zustand stores for the states
  const [coverImage, setCoverImage] = useState<ImageSource | null>(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState<string | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchCover = async () => {
      setIsLoading(true);
      setError(null);
      
      try {
        const image = await checkAndFetchCover(book.isbn);
        setCoverImage(image ? { uri: URL.createObjectURL(image) } : null);
        console.log(coverImage);
      } catch (error) {
        setError((error as Error).message);
      } finally {
        setIsLoading(false);
      }
    };

    fetchCover();
  }, [book.isbn])

  return (
    <View w={105} h={150} >
      <View alignItems="center" justifyContent="center">
        {isLoading && (<Spinner color="#6247AA" size="large" />)}
        {error && (<View w={105} h={105} backgroundColor="#FF6969" alignItems="center" justifyContent="center">
          <Text>There was an error loading the cover.</Text>
          {console.log(error)}
        </View>)}
        {!coverImage && (<View w={105} h={105} backgroundColor="#FF6969" alignItems="center" justifyContent="center">
          <Text>There was no cover found.</Text>
        </View>)}
        {!isLoading && !error && coverImage && (
          <Image source={coverImage} style={{width: 'auto', height: 'auto'}} />
        )}
        <Text>{book.title}</Text>
        <Text>{book.author_name}</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}

checkAndFetchCover.ts
type CoverImage = Blob | null | undefined;

const checkAndFetchCover = async (isbnCodes: string[] | undefined): Promise<CoverImage> => {
  if (!isbnCodes) {
    return undefined;
  }

  const imagePromises: Promise<CoverImage>[] = isbnCodes.map((code) => {
    const imageUrl = `http://covers.openlibrary.org/b/isbn/${code}-M.jpg`;
    return fetch(imageUrl)
      .then((response) => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          console.log("Error in image", code);
          throw new Error('Image not found');
        }
        return response.blob();
      })
  });

  const images = await Promise.all(imagePromises);
  return images.find((image) => image !== null);
};

export default checkAndFetchCover;

I haven't tried much on this as I am not fully experienced using fetch requests and how to handle its errors.
